# Using a `tf.Tensor` as a Python `bool` is not allowed.

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow

I am new to tensorflow and I am now trying to calculate this value out of two sensors box1 and box2

```
min(box1[0]+box1[2] ,box2[0]+box2[2]) - max(box1[0], box2[0])
```

I get *Using a `tf.Tensor` as a Python `bool` is not allowed.*

I understand tensors do not contain values until the session is not executed. My loss depends on this calculation and I can't see how to correctly express it.

Comment: does [`tf.maximum`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/math_ops/basic_math_functions#maximum) help?

Answer (score 0):

The Python `min()` and `max()` functions do not work on TensorFlow `tf.Tensor` objects.  Instead, use the [`tf.minimum()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/math_ops/basic_math_functions#minimum) and [`tf.maximum()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/math_ops/basic_math_functions#maximum) ops as follows:

```
loss = tf.minimum(box1[0] + box1[2], box2[0] + box2[2]) - tf.maximum(box1[0], box2[0])
```